# "application.get_key > modules" will return :undefined

Tags: elixir

I want to get a list of the modules in a certain namespace at the compile time, as a macro.

```
defmodule MyApp.MyModuleLoader do
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote bind_quoted: [opts: opts] do

      a1 = :application.get_key(:my_app)
      modules = :application.get_key(:my_app, :modules)

      IO.puts("****:a1: #{Kernel.inspect(a1)}")
      IO.puts("****:modules: #{Kernel.inspect(modules)}")

      # ====> :undefined

      # filter out the ones I don't need...
      # ....
    end
  end
end
```

I'll then `use MyModuleLoader` in a schema-model module.
But it'll print out `:undefined` for both variables during compilation.

Why? How to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you should back up and explain a bit more about the final goal you're trying to achieve with this introspection?  I suspect that you might be running into compile-time "order of operations" problems -- i.e. maybe you're trying to read from the Application config before it has finished hydrating, but I confess I'm fuzzy on the specifics of how bootstrapping may affect when certain values are available.

Comment: @Everett maybe you should explain a bit more about the reason you want me to explain that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we add `Application.ensure_loaded(:my_app)` like:

```
defmodule MyApp.MyModuleLoader do
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote bind_quoted: [opts: opts] do
      Application.ensure_loaded(:my_app) # <-

      a1 = :application.get_key(:my_app)
      modules = :application.get_key(:my_app, :modules)

      IO.puts("****:a1: #{Kernel.inspect(a1)}")
      IO.puts("****:modules: #{Kernel.inspect(modules)}")

      # ====> :undefined

      # filter out the ones I don't need...
      # ....
    end
  end
end
```

Then the output (ran via `iex -S mix`) will be:

```
****:a1: :undefined
****:modules: {:ok, [<list of modules>]}
```

After changing `IO.puts(...)` to `IO.inspect(...)` we get the same output from `mix compile` command.